# Get the Max value from objects array in C#

Tags: c#

I have an array which have objects, these objects have a string, a integer and a char properties.

```
Person[] people = new Person[1]; //Declare the array of objects

[...] This code is irrelevant

Person person = new Person(name, age, gender); //This creates instance a new object
people.SetValue(person, i); //is just a variable which increase in a c
Array.Resize(ref people, people.Length + 1);  //Change array  size 
i++; // Autoincrement
```

[...] More code to fill the values that works

From all the objects person stored in people array, i want to get the person's age max value (age property is integer value)

Comment: The max value itself, or the person (or people) with that max value? If the former, then you can just use `people.Max(person => person.Age);` Also, don't do manual array resizing like this. Use a `List<Person>`, which will handle resizing for you.

Comment: "is just a variable which increase in a c" what is "a c"?

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way is to use LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;

var maxVal = people.Max(x => x.Age); // get highest age
var person = people.First(x => x.Age == maxVal); // get someone with such an age
```

Comment: That's a poor use of linq. You need to make two passes of the list. You only need make one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your Person class looks something like this: -

```
class Person
{
  public int Age { get; private set; }
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public string Gender { get; private set; }

  // constructor etc
}
```

**Improvements**

If you have an Enumerable of `Person`, i.e. 'people', for which I recommend you use a container with an interface such as an IList, i.e: -

```
IList<Person> people = new List<Person>();
```

As this will save you from having to resize your array manually.

**Solution**

To acquire the greatest age, you can do something like: -

```
var max = people.Max(p => p.Age);
```

**Further reading**

This is a Linq query; more information can be found here: -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx

There are a lot of 'cool' things you can do with linq, such as selecting an enumerable of ages, i.e.

```
var ages = people.Select(p => p.Age);
```

This would return an enumerable containing the age of each person in your list. If you wanted all those over a certain age, you can use `Where`, i.e: -

```
var above = people.Where(p => p.Age > 65);
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using an array if you're going to resize it every time you add a new item. That's what the generic `List` class is for. You can write:

```
List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
Person person = new Person(name, age, gender);
People.Add(person);
```

The `List` takes care of resizing the backing array when it needs to. It's much easier and more efficient than resizing an array every time you add an item.

To get the maximum age, you can use one of the LINQ expressions shown in the other answers. If you want the record that has the maximum value, you have to iterate over the list:

```
Person maxItem = People[0];
foreach (Person person in People)
{
    if (person.Age > maxItem.Age)
    {
        maxItem = person;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 6.0 we have now a new method for this:

```
using System.Linq;

Person olderPerson = people.MaxBy(x => x.Age);
```

There is also MinBy if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the comment left by @dlev, in that you shouldn't be using traditional [`Arrays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.array%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but rather use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which automatically handles resizing of your collection.

Additionally because both [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.array%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) both implement IEnumerable you can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) to manipulate your elements, in fact take a look at the [whole list of methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckzcawb8.aspx) available to you.

Specific examples in for your scenario:

```
var maxVal = people.Max(x => x.Age);
var person = people.First(x => x.Age == maxVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do you:

```
Person[] persons = {};
Person oldest = persons.Aggregate( (x,y) => x.Age > y.Age ? x : y ) ;
```

Or roll you own:

```
static T FindMax<T>( this IEnumerable<T> items , Func<T,T,int> comparer  ) where T:class
{
  T max = null ;
  foreach ( T item in items )
  {
    if ( item == null ) { continue ; }
    if ( max == null ) { max = item ; continue ; }

    // check current item against max.
    // if current item is "greater than" the current max
    // replace it.
    int cc = comparer(item,max) ;
    if ( cc > 0 )
    {
      max = item ;
    }
  }
  return max ;
}
```

Usage:

```
Person[] persons = LoadPersons() ;
Person oldest = persons.FindMax<Person>( (x,y) => x.Age < y.Age ? -1 : x.Age > y.Age ? +1 : 0 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

What has been suggested above will work if the list is relatively small (less 1000 objects).  This is because all of the above methods use sequential search. For performance purposes (speed), applying a qsort approach is much more efficient.  For example:

```
class PersonAgeComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
    public Int32 Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {                
        if (x.Age > y.Age) return 1;
        if (x.Age < y.Age) return -1;

        return 0; // must be equal
    }
}

class Person
{
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}

static void Run1()
{
    Random rnd = new Random((Int32)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        persons.Add(new Person() { Age = rnd.Next(100) });
    }

    persons.Sort(new PersonAgeComparer());

    // The oldest but you may have dups (same age)
    Person oldest = persons[persons.Count - 1];

}
```